# Unable to mock a function call from a function call from the test function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have an issue with testing and I was hoping for some help.

A colleague of mine pointed me towards unittest.mock and patch and they seem to be exactly what I need, but I am unable to get this working correctly.

Problem written: I have my test case which calls and tests a function (foo) in a python file (fooFile) which calls another function (bar) in another python file (barFile). The bar function is what I need to mock from the test file.

Example code:

barFile.py

```py
#homedir.lib.barFile.py

def bar(object2):
    return False
```

fooFile.py

```py
#homedir.api.fooFile.py
from homedir.lib.barFile import bar

def foo(object1):
    result = bar(object1['item1'])
    if result:
        return 200
    else:
        return 400
```

testFooFile.py -- no mocking

```py
#homedir.tests.testFooFile.py
from homedir.api.fooFile import foo

def testFoo():
    payload = {"item1": "nothing"}
    result = foo(payload)
    assert result == 200
```

Basically, from the testFooFile.py file, I need to mock the bar function and get that to return True. I can only call bar through foo and this is where my issue lies. I can mock the bar function fine, but only when I call it directly from the testFile, not when it is called by the foo function. Here is somewhat along the lines of what I currently have.

testFooFile.py -- current idea

```py
#homedir.tests.testFooFile.py
from unittest.mock import patch
from homedir.api.fooFile import foo

@patch('homedir.lib.barFile.bar')
def testFoo(mock_bar):
    mock_bar.return_value = True

    payload = {"item1": "nothing"}
    result = foo(payload)
    assert result == 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the path you are patching should be `homedir.api.fooFile.bar`. You need to patch the instance of `bar()` that `foo()` is using, which is located in `fooFile.py`.